# Javafx tableview column value from event handler

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to take a value of table column from a event handler in Javafx? 
The task is I need to click a button, calculate functions, and return the value to the column.

I have this working:

```
data.add(new Person(id, name));
```

I have this:

```
TableColumn nameCol = new TableColumn ("name");
nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
// And id as well.
TableColumn resultsCol = new TableColumn ("Results");
resultsCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("results"));
```

And this:

```
add.setOnAction (e -> {
// I don't know what to put
});
```

Because id and name column are already working, what should I do to separately add a new value to the column from a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your CellValueFactories are pulling values directly from your Person object you would need to update the variables in the particular row's Person object when your button is clicked. You can do this with simple setter methods.

You could also use a technique like this to create a table with cells that can be edited with a click: http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2012/04/javafx-2-editable-tableview.html?m=1

I have successfully implemented this technique in my applications.